How to read a text file line by line and use it in JSON body of REST API message in Jmeter?
I have the data in a text (.txt) file and not in CSV. Each line is a long JSON message. I need to read the file line by line and pass it to JSON body of my REST API message. I tried using a JDBC pre-processor using Groovy but it gets only ne line. Any help would be appreciated.
In my HTTP request (only line of code is: ${extractedLine} ), I am trying to send the messages extracted from my text file one by one (for every line extracted from a the .txt file, one request will be submitted) via JSR223 pre-processor with the following code.
java.io.File

// Replace with the actual path to your text file
def filePath = "/path/to/your/file.txt"

// Specify the line number to read (starting from 1)
def lineNumber = 1

def file = new File(filePath)
def lines = file.readLines()

if (lineNumber <= lines.size()) {
    def lineContent = lines[lineNumber - 1]
    vars.put("extractedLine", lineContent)
} else {
    log.warn("Line number $lineNumber is out of bounds. File contains ${lines.size()} lines.")
}


But it is retrieving only line#1 because I defined it as 1. How do I increase it for every request? Thanks

Also, I  would like to define the file only once, outside JSR223 PreProcessor but if I do that using a JSR223 sampler under once-only controller outside the HTTP request, it does not work


If you want to read the whole file you can use __FileToString() function

If you want to read the whole file using Groovy you can use something like:
def content = new File('/path/to/your/file.txt').text


If you want to do it only once - put the JSR223 Sampler under setUp Thread Group and save the value into a JMeter property
def content = new File('/path/to/your/file.txt').text
props.put('content', content)

then you will be able to access the value using __P() function where required like ${__P(content)}



Thx, Ivan. I don't want to read the whole file but read a line and send it to HTTP Request and read the next line and use it HTTP request and so on...

Then go for __StringFromFile() function or better CSV Data Set Config
